# Search implementation

Tags: javascript, html, regex, search

Search on my site is implemented using regular expression:

```
RegExp(name, 'i')
```

where "name" is value of input block.
The problem is that dot matches any character and when I input dot, search gives wrong results. How should I change pattern of regular expression to exclude this issue?

Comment: What regular expression are you using? There is no dot here.

Comment: Escape the regular expression

Comment: If you don't want regular expression functionality, why are you using a regular expression?

Comment: I think, I did not explain correctly. In variable "name" could be any text, including letters, digits and punctuation signs. The way I want my regular expression to work: if there are dots in my search text, i want it to be determined not as regular expression metacharacter, which means any character except newline, but as an ordinary dot symbol. I know how to make it, when I set reg exp pattern by myself (like /\\./), but I don't know how to add this pattern to pattern, that is being set by "name" variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow certain regular expressions, then you could do a search/replace to escape these values, such that eg `.` becomes `\.`.

You'd need to clarify in your prompt that certain regular expressions will be treated as literals.

Answer (score 0):

You should create some regex escapper to escape all meta characters.

I think this function will fit: (found in [Is there a RegExp.escape function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript))

```
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
};
```